# How can I verify this URL directs to an image?

Tags: image, python-2.7, encoding

I'm working on a service, written in Python which, at one point, downloads images from given URLs and stores them on a server.

This service does a check of the content-type returned from the URL and only downloads the image if it's content-type is 'image/jpeg', etc.

I recently came up against an interesting problem with the following URL:
http://www.nationaldentalreviews.org/Handlers/ImageDisplay.ashx?qUID=8597&qType=__ProfileMicroSite

This URL, when opened in a browser, displays an encoded string of some sort.

When used as the 'src' of an image tag, it renders an image.

```
<html>
<body>
  <img src = 'http://www.nationaldentalreviews.org/Handlers/ImageDisplay.ashx?qUID=8597&amp;qType=__ProfileMicroSite'>
</body>
</html>
```

The content-type of this URL is text/html

Is there any way, in Python, for me to identify that this URL directs to an image which can be used as a 'src'?

Comment: What's your Python version?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the built-in [`imghdr`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/imghdr.html) module:

```
>>> import imghdr
>>> import urllib2
>>> 
>>> url = 'http://www.nationaldentalreviews.org/Handlers/ImageDisplay.ashx?qUID=8597&qType=__ProfileMicroSite'
>>> data = urllib2.urlopen(url).read()
>>> 
>>> imghdr.what(None, data)
'jpeg'
>>> # To show that it's only checking the header; don't do this though
>>> imghdr.what('', data:10])
'jpeg'
>>> imghdr.what('', 'CORRUPT_OR_NOT_AN_IMAGE' + data)
>>> # The last call returns None
>>>
```

Comment: What is the significance of the -5?

Comment: Why the downvote? I'd appreciate the opportunity to fix any issues :).

Answer (score 1):

Retrieve the image data and use https://docs.python.org/2/library/imghdr.html .

Answer (score 0):

The encoded string you are seeing is the binary contents of a jpeg. The server is setting the content type header incorrectly to text/html so your browser is attempting to display it as html instead of as a jpeg.

You could download the file and use the python image library to attempt to open the image, PIL will throw an exception if it's not an image.

```
>>> from PIL import Image
>>> im = Image.open("foo.jpg")
>>> im
<PIL.JpegImagePlugin.JpegImageFile image mode=RGB size=229x103 at 0x21A3300>
>>> im = Image.open("html.jpg")
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "c:\python27\lib\site-packages\PIL\Image.py", line 1980, in open
    raise IOError("cannot identify image file")
IOError: cannot identify image file
>>>
```